# How to rotate an image in TouchableOpacity

Tags: react-native

I tried to rotate image in TouchableOpacity element. My code works perfectly on iOS but it does not work on android.

My Code:

```js
<View style={commonStyle.topArea}>
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <Image
        resizeMode="stretch"
        source={this.props.playerHand[0].image}
        style={[
            commonStyle.card,
            { transform: [{ rotate: '-10deg' }] },
        ]}
        />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <Image
        resizeMode="stretch"
        source={this.props.playerHand[1].image}
        style={[commonStyle.card, { transform: [{ rotate: '0deg' }] }]}
        />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <Image
        resizeMode="stretch"
        source={this.props.playerHand[2].image}
        style={[commonStyle.card, { transform: [{ rotate: '10deg' }] }]}
        />
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Result

[This is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWe1N.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android don't support overflowing views. You can increase the size of the container instead. Add the rotation on the touchableopacity instead of the image and add flex:1 to your "top area".

Comment: It works but when i touch to image i get type casting exception. `java.lang.string cannot be cast to double`

Comment: This has probably nothing to do with the rotation, could you post your entire file?

Comment: Of course. [View on gist](https://gist.github.com/berkaygure/0ea3d0580a016d9eff5a55052ada0b84)

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Are you sure that "this.props.playerHand[2].image" always returns a resource and not a string url or an empty sting?

Comment: Touching should not do anything since yout havn't provided any onPress property to your TouchableOpacitys.

Comment: Yes, it always returns resource. I don't get any error when use TouchableHighlight instead of TouchableOpacity. [Error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdhwv.png)

Comment: What happens if you add onPress={() => {}} to your TouchablOpacities?

Comment: Unfortunately didn't change anything. But i wrapped TouchableOpacity with Animated.View and i rotate this view. Now works. Thanks for your help